# java.lang.out of memory error Android Bitmap Factory

Tags: java, android, memory

A've tried to recycle the bitmap and everything else that I found on google, but the problem is still here... Here is my code:

```
final SampleView mainPogled = new SampleView(this);

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
    options.inDither = true;

    pozadinap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nivoapozadina, options);
    playButtonp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play, options);

    pozadina = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pozadinap, s_width, s_height, false);
    playButton = Bitmap.createBitmap(playButtonp);
```

At the and I draw the bitmaps into a canvas..

Here is the error:

> 06-14 14:21:16.452: W/dalvikvm(1930): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ab7ba8)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): Process: com.hv.snake, PID: 1930
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:809)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:786)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:718)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:594)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.hv.snake.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:56)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   06-14 14:21:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I've posted the error in the first post, you can see it now.

Comment: what is on line MainMenu.java:56?

Comment: pozadina = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pozadinap, s_width, s_height, false);

Comment: Show the full code including where you recycle the bitmaps.

Comment: @user3330053 maybe that your width and height is too big

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after 2 days... [This](http://mobi-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-if-you-want-to-create-and.html) article helped me a lot.

In the onDestroy() method, first I recycle all the bitmaps from the activity, then I set them all to null and after that I call System.gc(). E.g.

```
public void onDestroy() {      

    super.onDestroy();

    background.recycle();
    background = null;
    System.gc();
 }
```

I hope this will help someone.